# Query Process Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set in SQL Server that I have created but I need to get a true or false by Event ID if the Triggers were done in order based on the steps listed in the Step column..  The data below shows the steps were done out of order so I want to query the EventID and a value telling me it wasn't done in order.  Picture of the data can be found at the link below..

Thank you in advance for your help

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5TX97oiRQrHX3c1aG1hUFAxWFE/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Which dbms? (Triggers are typically not ANSI compliant...)

Comment: Don't post pictures. Post sample data as formatted text, SQL scripts to setup your sample tables and expected output as formatted text. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So each STEP in your table shall equal the previous STEP + 1. And you want to output the wrong records, e.g. Log5 Step=13 ExpectedStep=5. Yes? Which DBMS?

Comment: Sorry this is in SQL..

Comment: I want to know if the steps in the step column were done out of order.

Comment: SQL is a language. There are many DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.) that use different SQL dialects. So again: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "I want to know if the steps in the step column were done out of order." So you just want a query that returns 'NO' in your case, because in your example the steps are not in order (step 13 too early, step 5 too late etc.) Step 17 is done too late, too, but if it were in the right place (between 16 and 18), but still done thrice, would that be considered "in order"? Events with no steps (like Log25) can be ignored right? They are neither "in order" nor "out of order", but just not relevant for the query. Yes?

Comment: Sorry this is in SQL Server..

Comment: Yes just yes or no if they were done in order..

Comment: Duplicates don't matter, if 17 was done between 16 and 18 then it is in order..  Events with no steps can be ignored.    So I can pull the sameple results into a temp table, remove the ones with no steps, remove the duplicates, etc..  And just want to know if the steps were done in order or not..  In some cases steps will be missing like step 24 is missing in the sample data.

Comment: So steps 23 and 25 are in order, because no step 24 exists?

Comment: In that circumstance that 24 is missing and 25 comes after 23, and all other steps are in the correct order, then it would be considered in order overall..

Comment: I've posted an answer. Still, it would be great if you added the table to your request, instead of the link to a picture that may disappear some time. This request and answer may be useful to other persons, but of course only as long as they are able to see the complete request.

Comment: There will be multiple Event ID's in the data ( the first column) with their own step numbers to be evaluated.. I ran your code against the sample data and it stopped at row where the steps went out of order which is perfect.. I then ran it again a clean Event ID that was in order and it didn't work correctly.. I had steps 1 to 25, all in order, datetime all in order and it stopped at step 10

Comment: Its something to do with the Step numbers..  If I change the step numbers to two digits then it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Why are date and time in separate columns? This doesn't seem to make sense here and complicates data access (you must combine the two in order to compare the time with another).

However, the task is rather easy: Is there any record for which an earlier record exists with a higher step number?

```
select
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from events as this_step
    where exists
    (
      select *
      from events as earlier_step
      where cast(earlier_step.dates as datetime) + cast(earlier_step.logtime as datetime) <
            cast(this_step.dates as datetime) + cast(this_step.logtime as datetime)
      and earlier_step.step > this_step.step
    )
  ) then 
    'ERROR'
  else
    'OKAY'
  end as status;
```

Comment: There will be multiple Event ID's in the data ( the first column) with their own step numbers to be evaluated..  I ran your code against the sample data and it stopped at row where the steps went out of order which is perfect..  I then ran it again a clean Event ID that was in order and it didn't work correctly..  I had steps 1 to 25, all in order, datetime all in order and it stopped at step 10.

Comment: I figured out the problem.. I was leaving a space in a table and using an update statement to pull the value but the space wasn't as an int..  So create the table and pulled the step, casted it as an int, and it worked perfectly..  Thank you for the help!